# MSChart StackedBar Chart - Display totals at end of bar column

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, mschart, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a MSChart StackedBar Chart with totals label at the end of the columns as in the image below (in red).

A) First, is this possible?
B) Second, is it possible to reposition the series labels?

[image]

Thanks in advance,
-Aaron

Comment: Hi , how you have displayed horizontal bars in MsChart and text over chart bars?

Comment: @Airn5475, I am trying to plot the stackbar chr as you have- not been able to plot, would you mind please posting how you wrote your code to graph the chart. Would really appreciate the help. thanks.